# Error while Publishing in infoformlibrary

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, infopath-rules

[image]

Hi, I have encountered this error while publishing info form list in **SharePoint online** library has checked all documents there is no duplicity or network issue. Help me to resolve this Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Tenant name is still visible in the other dialog. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue only occur in one form library?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Create a new form library in the SharePoint online site and then publish the form to the form library to check if the same issue will occur.
2. Login to the SharePoint online site with the current user to check if the user has the permission in the SharePoint online site.
3. Clear IE cache.
4. Create a new InfoPath form and publish to a new form library to check if the same will occur.
5. Check if the Desktop Experience is enabled on the server which install the InfoPath. Go to Server Manager and start Add Roles and Features wizard to check. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[How to Fix InfoPath Form Publishing Error – SharePoint 2013.](http://tharindupg.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-fix-infopath-form-publishing.html)

Update:

You could submit a service request for the issue in Admin Center.

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Amy_MSFT I have tried the same thing, created a form library and tried to publish to the form library. But the same issue. Also I have enabled the desktop experience, though I am trying to publish to SharePoint online sites. I have tried with different laptop also. still the issue is same. And the user is a tenant admin, and I have tried to publish to different SharePoint sites, but no luck.

Comment: I suggest you could submit a service request.